# Acer Ferrari 3000 in portrait display mode

Tags: display, amd-radeon

I have a [Acer Ferrari 3000](http://www.techradar.com/reviews/pc-mac/laptops-portable-pcs/laptops-and-netbooks/acer-ferrari-3000-17033/specification) notebook that I like to connect to a external display and show it in [portrait mode](http://www.technologybestpractices.com/images/willsmonoitors.jpg).

The computer runs a ATI Radeon 9200 graphic chipset and I can't find the setting for portrait and start believe the graphics card actually doesn't support it? I've looked at the latest drivers and can see that this has changed.

What are my options? Can I buy some sort of external graphics thingy or other possible solutions will get up votes!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a guide to adjusting the orientation of your computer monitor using an ATI video card.

**[Windows XP: Screen Rotation Using an ATI Video Card](http://grok.lsu.edu/Article.aspx?articleId=4642)**

[image]

Note: these options are only available if the ATI Catalyst Control Center is installed.

Comment: But I don't have that rotate option? Why can that be?

Comment: Ok thanks. I'll RUN to the office tomorrow and install ATi Catalyst Control Center. If that work Molly has one big upvote and accepted answer coming his/her way!